# Traverse all possible paths of an array with javascipt using async

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, express

I' am a begginer with Javascript and I am currently try to find all possible paths of a returned JSON object from an axios GET request.Every item can belong to one or more groups, and one group can belong to an other group.
e.g.

```
{
  "name": "item1",
  "groupNames": [ "GROUPA" ]
}

{
    "name": "GROUPA",
    "groupNames": [
        "GROUPB"
    ]

}
....
{
    name: "GROUPZ"
    "groupNames": [
      
    ]
}
```

My issue is that my code is working only if a item name has only one parent groupName in the array.
What if we have more than one parentgroupNames? e.g

```
{
  "name": "item1",
  "groupNames": [ "GROUPA","GROUC",GROUBD ]
}
...
```

My current code:

```
let parent = 'item1';
 do{ 
   let endpoint = ${process.env.OPENHAB_HOST}:${process.env.OPENHAB_PORT}/rest/items/${parent}?recursive=false 
    result = await getAxiosRequest(endpoint,{},res); // get request to specific endpoint
    parent = result.data.groupNames; }
while(result.data.groupNames.length !== 0 )
```

Comment: What exactly is the *output* or variable content you expect to have after this loop?

Answer (score 0):

To find all the parent groups for an item that has multiple parent groups, you can modify your code as follows:

Initialize an array called parents to store the parent groups that you find.
In the loop, instead of assigning parent to result.data.groupNames, iterate over result.data.groupNames and add each group to the parents array.
After the loop, parents will contain all the parent groups for the given item.
Here's how the modified code would look:

```
let parent = 'item1';
let parents = []; // initialize array to store parent groups

do { 
  let endpoint = `${process.env.OPENHAB_HOST}:${process.env.OPENHAB_PORT}/rest/items/${parent}?recursive=false`;
  result = await getAxiosRequest(endpoint,{},res); // get request to specific endpoint
  result.data.groupNames.forEach(group => parents.push(group)); // add each group to the parents array
  parent = result.data.groupNames;
} while(result.data.groupNames.length !== 0);

console.log(parents); // array of parent groups
```

This should work even if the item has multiple parent groups.

Comment: This code returns UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error, maybe because parent is an array and it is passed as a parameter to the endpoint? @Florian

Comment: great answer! just out of curiosity, did you get this from chatgpt?

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what the end result should be after the loop has ran, but I'll assume you would maybe *collect* the paths from the given item in an array.

As indeed you can get multiple groups, you need to either store them in a queue/stack for later processing, or use recursion (for the same reason).

Here is how it could look with recursion:

```
function async visit(parent) {
  const endpoint = `${process.env.OPENHAB_HOST}:${process.env.OPENHAB_PORT}/rest/items/${parent}?recursive=false`;
  const {data} = await getAxiosRequest(endpoint, {}, res);
  const results = [];
  for (const group of data.groupNames) {
    results.push(...(await visit(group)).map(path => path.concat(group)));
  }
  return results;
}

visit('item1').then(paths => {
    // ....
});
```